# How to create a Bootstrap thumbnails grid

Tags: javascript, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have an unknown number of thumbs to display, here is an example of the HTML rendered:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="span3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img data-src="holder.js/260x180" alt="260x180" style="width: 260px; height: 180px;" src="mySrc">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="span3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img data-src="holder.js/260x180" alt="260x180" style="width: 260px; height: 180px;" src="mySrc">
            </a>
          </li><li class="span3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img data-src="holder.js/260x180" alt="260x180" style="width: 260px; height: 180px;" src="mySrc">
            </a>
          </li><li class="span3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img data-src="holder.js/260x180" alt="260x180" style="width: 260px; height: 180px;" src="mySrc">
            </a>
          </li><li class="span3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img data-src="holder.js/260x180" alt="260x180" style="width: 260px; height: 180px;" src="mySrc">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="span3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img data-src="holder.js/260x180" alt="260x180" style="width: 260px; height: 180px;" src="mySrc">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="span3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img data-src="holder.js/260x180" alt="260x180" style="width: 260px; height: 180px;" src="mySrc">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

---

**Here is the result:**
[image: screen shot]

**Question** : Since I build the UI dynamically, how can I avoid the margin on the second row without creating another `<div class="row-fluid">`

**Update** IE8 solution is required

Comment: Will the number of items per line change?

Comment: could change, basically it is one line with an unknown number of thumbs <div class="row-fluid"><ul class="thumbnails"><li>....<li>

Comment: Ye but my thinking is, assuming the width of its parent won't change you will always have the 5th li at the start?

Comment: This is way behind you now but I would just change the location of the margin to the other side i.e. on the right rather than the left. It make sense to think that when a thumbnail gets on the page it should say "whoever else comes next stay this far away from me" this would always be fine even if no one else came along rather than say "when I get here, I stay this far away from whoever is here" which as your question shows might not apply if it was the first one around. You would also get consistent column alignment that way (sorry I think in analogies hence the story)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the width won't change of the LI's parent using **:nth-child(4n)** should work to target the `x` element.

```
.row-fluid li:nth-child(4n) {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) for details on how to write formulas for :nth-child().

A very very basic [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZJSy/) displaying it working.

**Update**

To work with IE8 just use jQuery (assuming you're using it)

```
$('.row-fluid li:nth-child(4n)').css({'margin':'10px'});
```

I do believe that should do the trick.

Comment: my apologies, I should have state that I need an IE8 solution too. I'll accept the answer if no other solution will pop. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: actually I'm using angularJS without JQ ... but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Script works. I had css hack formula for same but it didnt work in IE7,8 and safari.

Answer (score 3):

I had a case where the margin was ok to have, but it had to be consistent on all rows.

You could achieve this by adding in a blank `<li style="display:none"></li>` to the start of the list. That way Bootstrap targets the margin removal on a `<li>` that isnt shown.

Having a margin may not be acceptable, but I feel this is an elegant solution without the need for mixing style into js.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, not clean, but a fast workaround was the following:

```
.row {
   margin-left: 0px !important;
   margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```